# GRUB set address kernel is loaded at

Tags: grub

How would I go about changing the address GRUB tries to load my kernel at without using the linker?
I would like to do this from GRUB config files.

Comment: Your question would be considered off-topic on StackOverflow since it is not a programming question. There are other communities like [superuser](http://superuser.com/) [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) where this question would be more appropiate.

Answer (score 1):

Boot your machine. When you get to the grub menu press `c`. You will go into `grub prompt`.

With `ls` you can view your devices and partitions. Look through your partitions until you have the correct one.

```
ls
ls (hd0,gpt1)/
ls (hd0,gpt2)/
ls (hd1,gpt1)/
ls (hd1,gpt2)/
...
```

Let's assume the files are located at `hd0,gpt2` and it is the only USB device -> `/dev/sda2`. We also assume at the root folder `/` there is your kernel `vmlinuz` and an initial ramdisk `initrd.img`.

Type into your grub prompt:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 rootdelay=10
initrd /initrd.img
```

When your machine boots correctly you can put this into your grub config files.